# Finding maximum of two variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Given $X$ is uniform on $[0, 10]$. Let $$Y = \max(5, X).$$ Determine Var(Y).

I'm familiar with how to find the variance of a uniform random variable, as well as the max of two random variables. However, I'm a bit confused about the 5.

For the max order statistic:

$P(\text{max}(5,X) \leq Y) = P(X \leq y)P(5 \leq y)$
Beyond this I'm stuck as to what to do next.

Also, I know that the variance would be $\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$ for a uniform random variable on interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: If you can do it for two random variables then recognize in $5$ a random variable $Z$ with $Z(\omega)=5$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$Y$ and $Y^2$ are nonnegative random variables so that:

$$\mathbb{E}Y=\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(Y>y\right)dy=\int_{0}^{5}1dy+\int_{5}^{10}P\left(X>y\right)dy$$

and:

$$\mathbb{E}Y^{2}=\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(Y^{2}>y\right)dy=\int_{0}^{25}1dy+\int_{25}^{100}P\left(X^{2}>y\right)dy$$

Comment: For E[X^2], I can see that the first part would equal 25. For the second integral, is that just the survival function of y(i.e. 1 - F(y))?

Comment: It is the survival function that is connected to $X^2$. So $1-F_{X^2}(y)$

Comment: Ok, so it would be (100-y)/(100-25) = 100/75 - y/75?

Comment: For $y\in\left[25,100\right]$ we have $P\left(X^{2}>y\right)=P\left(\sqrt{y}<X\leq10\right)=\frac{1}{10}\left(10-\sqrt{y}\right)$. That is the integrand of the second part.

Comment: Ok I see. So using the same process, the second integral for $E[Y]$ would be $P(y < X \leq 10) = \frac{1}{10}(1-y)$?

Comment: You probably mean $\frac1{10}(10-y)$ on interval $[5,10]$. Yes that is the integrand of the second integral for $\mathbb EY$.

Answer (score 0):

The cdf of $Y$ is
$$P(Y\leq y)=P(\max(5,X) \leq y) =$$
$$=P(\max(5,X) \leq y\cap X\leq5)+P(\max(5,X) \leq y\cap X>5)=$$
$$=P(X\leq 5\leq y)+P(5<X\leq y)$$

$$=
\begin{cases}
\frac12+\frac{y-5}{10},& \text{ if } 10\ge y>5\\
0,&\text{ if } y\le 5\\
1,&\text{ if } y>10. 
\end{cases}$$

So, $Y=5$ with probability $\frac12$ and is uniformly distributed over $[5,10]$ also with probability $\frac12$.

Then

$$E[Y]=\frac12 5 +\frac12 \frac{15}2=\frac{25}4.$$

I just hope that calculating the variance will not cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

$E(Y)=\int\limits_{0}^{10} \frac{max(X,5)}{10}dx=\int\limits_{0}^{5}\frac{5}{10}dx+\int\limits_{5}^{10}\frac{x}{10}dx$, as if $0 \leq X \leq 5$ then $max(X,5)=5$and if $5 \leq X \leq 10$, then $max(X,5)=X$.